# What type of visa do I need if I want to travel with my partner (unmarried) to the UK to visit his children

Tags: visas, uk

He is willing to pay my air ticket and we will be accommodated by one of his children. I have a business and he is a pensioner in this case. We have lived together physical for four years in Uganda. Tell me what documents I need to provide

Comment: How long do you plan to travel for?

Comment: We will be spending a month

Comment: @Grace You can use this https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y to find out

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa). It can be used:

> - for leisure, for example on holiday or to see your family and friends

This visa can be issued for 6 months.

The [documents you have to provide](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) are:

> - the dates you’re planning to travel to the UK
> - details of where you’ll be staying during your visit
> - how much you think your trip will cost
> - your current home address and how long you’ve lived there
> - your parents’ names and dates of birth
> - how much you earn in a year
>
> You might also need:
>
> - details of your travel history for the past 10 years (as shown in your passport)
> - your employer’s address and telephone number
> - your partner’s name, date of birth, and passport number
> - the name and address of anyone paying for your trip
> - the name, address and passport number of any family members you have in the UK
> - details of any criminal, civil or immigration offences you have committed

Here is a list of [all supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) you can choose to provide.

You also [need to prove](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility):

> - you’ll leave the UK at the end of your visit
> - you’re able to support yourself and any dependents for the duration of your trip
> - you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey and any other costs relating to your visit
> - you have proof of any business or other activities you want to do in the UK, as allowed by the [Visitor Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)